# Python file import from subdirectory can't use pygame module

Tags: python, import, pygame, subdirectory

I have a **game.py** like following

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
from classes import *
```

my folder tree is like this:

```
game.py
/classes
   __init__.py
   Options.py
```

**init**.py file:

```
from .Ms import *
from .Options import *
```

and in my **Options.py** file i have this code:

```
class Options:
   clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Basicly this is the structure i am going with. And i am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Abuzittin\Desktop\dalek\FINAL2\game.py", line 8, in <module>
    from classes import *
File "C:\Users\Abuzittin\Desktop\dalek\FINAL2\classes\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .Options import *
File "C:\Users\Abuzittin\Desktop\dalek\FINAL2\classes\Options.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Options:
File "C:\Users\Abuzittin\Desktop\dalek\FINAL2\classes\Options.py", line 8, in Options
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) #pygame screen variable
```

NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You also have to `import pygame` in your Options.py file.

BTW, don't use `from module import *` imports, because they make code harder to read and can cause problems if you have the same name for functions or classes in different modules. You can keep the `from pygame.locals import *`, but don't do that with your own modules. I'm not sure about the __init__ file, though.